# Как сделать такую шифровку в Java

Tags: java, python, шифрование, хеширование

Python:

```
import base64
import hmac
from hashlib import sha1

data = '{"hello":"world"}'

mac = hmac.new(
           bytes.fromhex("715ffccf8c0536f186bf127a16c14682827fc581"), 
           data.encode("utf-8"),
           sha1
)
signature = base64.b64encode(
    bytes.fromhex("01") + mac.digest()
).decode("utf-8")
print(signature)  # AU/qFnFOpzz5JEEu6syDDqNg4p54
```

Как реализовать это на джаве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

        Charset utf = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(new BigInteger("715ffccf8c0536f186bf127a16c14682827fc581", 16 ).toByteArray(), "HmacSHA1"));
        byte [] a = mac.doFinal("{\"hello\":\"world\"}".getBytes(utf));
        byte [] b = new byte[a.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 1, a.length);
        b[0] = 1;
        System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(b), utf));
        // AU/qFnFOpzz5JEEu6syDDqNg4p54

    }

}
```